# Sub image from mat with Opencv4android

Tags: android, opencv

i want to get a sub-image (the one bounded by the red box below) from an image (Mat format). how do i do this with opencv4 android ?

Comment: So where is the image?.

Comment: i can't post an image because i haven't 10 reputation :(

Comment: i can describe you my image :  the red color still red and all is in black , i wanna to extract the object in red color.

Comment: Or you can paste the image here http://imgur.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

- Convert to [gray scale](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).
- [Threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html) the gray.
- [Find contour and it's bounding box.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)
- Using the boundbox crop the ROI like

  ```
   Rect R; //bounding box for contour
   Mat src;//source image
   Mat cropped=src(R); //Crop the image
  ```

Note: You should convert all these to Java or Use JNI to use C++ directly.

Comment: I applied the contour and I have this result http://imgur.com/DQKMphS , but i think that problem not resolved because i have a war in my mind : how extract region with this contour!!!!!!!! please help me :)

Comment: But the above image contain many object, I thought it may be red object with black background.

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed OpenCV for android SDK, probably you are going to  do this in Java right?

Comment: the first result is: http://imgur.com/PF5vG6R                       but when i applied the contour for the original image i get this result imgur.com/DQKMphS , by the way i applied "Core.ellipse" to detect circle object. So my probleme how to extract this object :(

Comment: Yes i do it , the environement is installed

Comment: yes i have seen this application, but me i used  opencv for android to develop code to obtain these two above images